# Showing background 256 colours with tput

Tags: bash, tput

I am display the 256 colors for tput by colouring tho background colour using the following bash function.

```
 tput-bgcolours ()
 {
    for color in {0..255}; do
        bg=$(tput setab $color)
        echo -n $bg" "
    done
    echo $(tput sgr0)
 }
```

How can I pass a range of values to the function rather that looking all colours from 0 to 255?

Comment: Your original version made more sense than this one.

Comment: Have had a go at passing parameters with defaults.

Comment: Take colors256() in https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/037 do `sed -i s/setaf/setab/g` and try it. It includes nice ways to select panels of colors.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```bsh
tput-bgcolours()
{
    for color in "$@"; do
        tput setab $color
        printf " "
    done
    tput sgr0
}

tput-bgcolours {0..10} {30..40}
```

The `"$@"` is the set of arguments to the function.  Now, the caller of the function can pass the values that they're interested in printing.

This also has the benefit that you don't *have* to use a range:

```bsh
tput-bgcolours 1 7 15 8 1
```

Comment: @Pietru Note that there's no _need_ to force the colors to be sequential.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of alternatives:

- `printf` is [in general](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/140633) preferred over `echo`.
- One do not need to `echo tput`

***sh compatible***

```bsh
tput-bgcolours() {
    for color in $(seq "$1" "$2"); do
        tput setab "$color"
        printf ' '
    done
    tput sgr0
}
```

***bash loop***

```bsh
tput-bgcolours() {
    for (( c = $1; c <= $2; ++c )); do
        tput setab "$c"
        printf ' '
    done
    tput sgr0
}
```

Usage:

```
tput-bgcolours FROM TO
```

I.e.

```
tput-bgcolours 0 16
```

You could of course also add a test in the functions like (`test if length of arg is empty`):

```
if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "$2" ]; then
    return 1
fi
```

or use defaults:

```
from=${1:-0}
to=${2:-255}
```

Comment: does (( color = $1; color <= $2; color++ )) not work in bash?

Comment: It is actually #!/bin/bash

Comment: I get "bash: ((: color <= : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<= ")"

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Do I need #!/bin/bash in my .bashrc ?

Comment: Apologies.  Solved, was doing a stupid thing before that.